# Actualizar vista automaticamente - Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo este código en el HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="seleccion.grupo">
    <option *ngFor="let grupo of grupos" value="{{grupo['id']}}">{{grupo['name']}}</option>
</select> &nbsp;

<button (click)="actualizarUsuarios()" class="boton-aceptar"></button>&nbsp;

<select [(ngModel)]="seleccion.usuario">
    <option *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios" value="{{usuario['id']}}">{{usuario['username']}}</option>
</select>
```

La idea es que cuando el usuario escoja un grupo, se muestre en el otro `select` los usuarios que pertenecen a ese grupo. Pero lo hago mediante un botón, y **necesito que se actualice la vista de forma automática**.

He leído sobre `(ngModelChange)` y he intentado aplicarlo pero no lo he conseguido tampoco.

> El método `actualizarUsuarios()` simplemente hace una petición GET
> para traer los usuarios que pertenecen a un grupo, que le paso por
> parámetro.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado con (ngModelChange)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he usado el select de esta forma para que funcione correctamente con el ngModelChangue.

```html
<select id="grupo" name="grupo" [(ngModel)]="seleccion.grupo" (ngModelChange)="actualizarUsuarios()">
  <option *ngFor="let grupo of grupos" [ngValue]="grupo.id"> {{grupo.name}} </option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="seleccion.usuario">
    <option *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios" value="{{usuario['id']}}">{{usuario['username']}}</option>
</select>
```

En el option en lugar de manejar un value, seria [ngValue] con el valor de el grupo

Answer (score 0):

Si la vista no detecta los cambios en el controlador deberias echarle un vistazo la interfaz [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) y [SimpleChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges) que permite diferenciar los parametros y realizar operaciones sobre dichos cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente estructura:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="seleccion.grupo"   >
    <option *ngFor="let grupo of usuariosPorGrupo | keyvalue">{{grupo.key}}</option>
</select> &nbsp;



<select [(ngModel)]="seleccion.usuario">

    <option *ngIf="!seleccion.grupo" disabled="true">Selecciona un grupo</option>
    <option *ngFor="let usuario of usuariosPorGrupo[seleccion.grupo]" >{{usuario}}</option>
</select>
```

Y en tu component.ts:

```
  seleccion = {
    grupo: "",
    usuario: ""
  };

  usuariosPorGrupo = {
    grupo1: ["usuario 1", "Usuario 4"],
    grupo2: ["Usuario 2", "Usuario 3"]
  };
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/seleccion-de-usuario-por-grupo?file=src/app/app.component.html)